# esata connections not showing in Windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, esata

Windows XP
Coolmaxusa External Enclosure HD 380 series
1 TB drive
Dynex Esata Card

All drivers have been installed.

Per the coolmaxusa manual, I am supposed to connect both the USB and eSata cable. The hard drive is recognized, but it recognizes it as a USB drive.

Shouldn't it be recognized as an Esata Drive?

Comment: have you tried to power it through the power adapter and connect to eSATA only

Answer (score 3):

I have a VanTec USB/eSATA enclosure very similar to what you've described.

If you connect it while the system is operating, **It uses whatever connection you connect first.**

If you connect USB first and then plug in eSATA, it will configure itself in USB mode for that power-on period.

If you connect with eSATA first and then plug in the USB, it lets the drive know you want eSATA mode. (Particularly because eSATA usually can't operate by itself in an external drive, it needs USB for the power).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its using esata and just says USB. I can give that a try, but the manual clearly said to connect both. I will try it tonight when I get home.

Will windows explorer say eSata? Windows XP is pretty old. I don't know if windows explorer will recognize the connection.

One interesting thing. When I went to computer management-> Disk Management. The external drive is showing as a SCSI drive. It is not a scsi controller. It is just a SATA drive, that I put in a cage. I am wondering if that is how windows recognizes eSata.

I ran a backup last night with Acronis. It was about 35 gbs. It took about 1.5 hours. It s

Comment: Depending on the driver written for that card it can show as a scsi device, did you initialize and format the drive while you were in disk management?

Comment: FYI, do not use the answer box to add information, edit your original post to do this, answer boxes are for Answers only, if you have a comment, then use the comment box.

Answer (score 1):

I also heard that depending on your SATAN controller, that you may need to restart the computer with esata plugged in and powered on to get it to show up. Try that?